# How do I merge 3 files to create a panel data?

Tags: regression, stata, panel-data

I have three different Stata files (each for three different years) and I want to estimate a fixed effects regression. My guess is that I need to merge those files in order to test my regression, but how do I do it? How do I give the time identification for the same variable in each of these files?

Comment: You merge data in Stata using the `merge` command (no surprise there).  Please give a representative example showing the current structure of your databases, the arrangement of the desired database, and a very important point: show us what you've tried, i.e. the code, and why it's not working. There's also an `append` command which does something different. See `help merge` and `help append` and report back if you have problems.

Comment: I tried to merge the files. And they merged -- I did it with data->combine data sets->merge two files. But I could not give the time identification for the variables (I serached for some code for it, but haven't found one). One file is a data set for consumption variables for the first year, another file is for the second year with the same consumption variables and the another one, with the same variables, for the third year.

Comment: Even if you're working with the GUI, the exact command is printed in the Results window. That code could be useful. You still don't show examples of your databases. I find it difficult to make sense out of "could not give the time identification for the variables". Please read the *asking* section in http://stackoverflow.com/help and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you don't `merge` (put the files side by side) such files, but `append` (put them on top of one another) them. Typically, the year or wave variable is already included, but when that is not the case you need to `generate` them before you `merge` the files. For more, just type in Stata `help merge`, `help append`, and `help generate`.

---

Preparing datasets should be *exactly* documented, so using the GUI is not the way to do this. Instead, you should do this using a .do file. For a good introduction on how to do good and reproducible research with Stata, see:

Long, J. S. (2009). *The workflow of data analysis using Stata*. College Station, TX: Stata Press.